# Windows 10 Update - Preventing Feature Updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I know there are workarounds for this, such as, including completely disabling Windows Update services, firewalling off access to the Windows Update servers, marking the connection as metered and disabling downloads over metered connections, etc, but I recently discovered that there is another way which I am unable to actually replicate.

Two VMs running Windows 10. One was forked via a backup snapshot from over a year ago (not used since, it was just a backup snapshot).

I applied the release target registry patch from here, modified to keep both at release 1809:
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/159624-how-specify-target-feature-update-version-windows-10-a.html

The clean fork from a year ago updated with the latest 1809 updates, and stayed and 1809, no attempt to update to 1903, which is now mandatory.

The one that has been used ignores this and auto-downloads 1903 regardless, even though the target version is set to 1809.

Now, I get that the latter is the intended behaviour, but for me it is **undesired** behaviour. It is near impossible to unpick the differences because of a year's worth of usage on the VM since the old snapshot and Windows is practically built out of obscurity and opaqueness.

So - question: I'm hoping somebody here might have some bright ideas on where exactly to look in various files or the registry for exactly what might be making the old fork stick with and obey the 1809 target, which the since-used VM does not. Was there perhaps a patch (if so what KB?) that might be responsible?

Any insight would be gratefully received.

Comment: With the release of Windows 10 version 2004, Microsoft removed the ability to defer feature updates and quality updates, but introduced a group policy that allows configure the feature update you want to receive.  However, there is a limit to that policy, in that once a feature update is unsupported the most applicable feature update will be pushed.  Long Term support versions must be used to avoid that.  The deferment changes don't apply to 1909 and earlier.

Comment: https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/28/control-windows-updates-with-sledgehammer-formerly-wumt-wrapper-script/

Comment: Download: https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/wumt_wrapper_script.html

Comment: Original post for sledgehammer (wumt)>>>>https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/sledgehammer-windows-10-update-control.72203/